# how can we pass the Flv format files to rtmp using VideoCore Library in ios

Tags: ios, rtmp, broadcasting, streaming-flv-video, videocore

Hi i am making an app based on broadcast using RTMP, videocore lib and Wowza server my Wowza server play only FLV file But i don't know how to pass FLV videos to server and how to encode H.264 codec if it is H.264 for videos and AAC for Audio then only it will Start the Broadcasting but I am using below code

```
switch(_session.rtmpSessionState)
            {
                case VCSessionStateNone:[_session continuousAutofocus];
                case VCSessionStatePreviewStarted:
                case VCSessionStateEnded:
                case VCSessionStateError:
                    NSLog(@"///////////////////////////////////////////////vcsession error%ld",(long)VCSessionStateError);



                    [_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:urlForStream
                                         andStreamKey:streamID];

                    break;
                default:
                    [_session endRtmpSession];
                    break;
            }
```

and below log displaying in console

Hi,

I tried connecting the my app from iOS 8.3 to RTMP server(Wowza) using VCSimpleSession. But i am unable to connect. Always returning state -11 (ClientStateNotConnected)

Please find the log below:

[736:267980] Creating context

[736:267980] Context creation succeeded

ClientState: 1

ClientState: 2

ClientState: 3

ClientState: 4

ClientState: 5

ClientState: 6

received server window size: 10000000

received peer bandwidth limit: 10000000 type: 2

received ping, sending pong.

Received invoke

pktId: 1

received invoke _result

tracked command: connect

ClientState: 7

received unknown packet type: 0x18

Received invoke

pktId: 2

received invoke _result

tracked command: connect

ClientState: 11